# How to serialize, send over network, deserialize a transaction envelope for multiple signatures?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, xdr

I'm trying to send over the network a base64 encoded string representing a partly signed envelope. I need to parse the string back to the original javascript object in order to add a new signature to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first serialization can be done via:

```
const base64str = transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR().toString('base64')
```

Then you have a base64 encoded string that can be safely transmitted over the network.

To restore it back to the original object you can do:

```
const tx = new Transaction(base64str)
```

Comment: You can also do transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64') but the types are wrong.

Comment: You are right.. the typings are not updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Encoding:** You can serialize the transaction by first converting to XDR (which is a binary format) and then converting to a base64 string so it can be sent over the wire.

```
// sign with empty signature to convert to a transaction envelope
signed, e := txn.Sign()
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to sign: ", e)
}

// convert to base64 (b64 is a string)
b64, e := signed.Base64()
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to convert to base64: ", e)
}
```

**Decoding:** Then you can decode the base64 string to binary and then build the transaction from the binary.

```
// decodeFromBase64 decodes the transaction from a base64 string into a TransactionEnvelopeBuilder
func decodeFromBase64(encodedXdr string) *b.TransactionEnvelopeBuilder {
    // Unmarshall from base64 encoded XDR format
    var decoded xdr.TransactionEnvelope
    e := xdr.SafeUnmarshalBase64(encodedXdr, &decoded)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(e)
    }

    // convert to TransactionEnvelopeBuilder
    txEnvelopeBuilder := b.TransactionEnvelopeBuilder{E: &decoded}
    txEnvelopeBuilder.Init()

    return &txEnvelopeBuilder
}
```

**Note:** *You will need to input the network passphrase when you decode it because it is not transmitted as part of the base64-encoded Transaction XDR*